# In EF Code First, how do I setup an one-to-many property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

So I have the following EF models:

```
[Table("Site")]
public class Store{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
[Table("Item")]
public class Item {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column("SiteID")]
    public int storeID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("storeID")]
    public Store store { get; set; }
}
```

So, going from Item->Store seem to be fine, the data populate.  But Store->Items doesn't populate.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you actually loading the information?

Comment: Entity Framework auto load!

Comment: Could you share the code where you are loading the information from the database?

Comment: There is no code, Entity Framework automatically load the information from database.  In anycase, I managed to solve this problem, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out, to build a one-to-many relationship, you need to use the InverseProperty.  Like this!

```
[Table("Site")]
public class Store {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("store")]
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

[Table("Item")]
public class Item {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column("SiteID")]
    public int storeID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("storeID")]
    public Store store { get; set; }
}
```

Everything load, event the Items collection.